# Отрисовка графика с graphview

Tags: java, android, graphics, material-design, design

Использую [библиотеку](http://www.android-graphview.org/) для отрисовки графика. Т.к. график отображает зависимость температуры и времени, а смена температуры это процес не дискретный то хотелось бы выводить не такой скачкообразный граф. В самой библиотеке не смог найти подобное. Может кто стыкался с подобным?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно что в библиотеке такие возможности не доступны с коробки. Использовал вычесление [скользящего среднего](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) для решения задачи. Клас для обработки значения:

```
class ExponentialMovingAverage(private val alpha : Double) {
    companion object {
        const val ALPHA_FILTER_INDEX : Double = 0.05
    }

    private var oldValue: Double? = null

    fun average(value: Double): Double {
        if (oldValue == null) {
            oldValue = value
            return value
        }

        val newValue = oldValue!! + alpha * (value - oldValue!!)
        oldValue = newValue
        return newValue
    }
}
```

где `ALPHA_FILTER_INDEX` это коефициент сглаживания от 0 до 1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]